# How do I find all numbers between 2 integers that are divisble by a third integer?

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to take three integers from the user, and find the numbers between two of them (startInt and endInt) that are divisible by the third integer (modulus), then print all the divisible numbers to a jTextField. I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm missing, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing.

Here is my code:

```
private void goButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    int startInt, endInt, modulus;
    startInt = Integer.parseInt(startTextField.getText());
    endInt = Integer.parseInt(endTextField.getText());
    modulus = Integer.parseInt(modulusTextField.getText());

    int intDistance = endInt - startInt;

    for (int loopCounter; loopCounter <= intDistance; loopCounter++)  {

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: `int loopCounter` needs an initial value--`int loopCounter = <some value>`... what do you want to start with?

Comment: In Java there is a `%` operator, which gives you the remainder when dividing numbers.  You want to loop from one number to the other, looking for when `loopCounter % modulus == 0`.

Comment: A hint for you: Java uses % as the modulus operator.  So, inside your loop you should test to see if "loopCounter % modulus" is equal to 0.

Comment: Sorry about that, alex, I'll be sure not to do that again. Thanks for the help guys, and I can't believe I missed declaring the initial value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find matches for all i values strictly between startInt and endInt which are divisible by modulus.

```
for(int i = startInt + 1; i < endInt; i++)
{
    if(i % modulus == 0)
    {
        //i is a match (i is divisible by modulus)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this works perfectly. I knew I was overthinking it.